# Create an External Cron Job using PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, cron-task

Is there a way to create an external cron job on a server using PHP?

I'm writing a Wordpress plugin that requires a scheduled task to run every 10 minutes. I'm aware of Wordpress's native WP-Cron but cannot use this because it depends on pageviews to execute. Creating the job manually through cPanel isn't an attractive option either because my userbase isn't very technical.

I have seen [some suggestions](http://www.iwebss.com/wordpress/519-wordpress-cron-job-setup-with-wp-cron-php) about using wget and the PHP command line tool for creating cron jobs. Could either of these approaches be executed from within a PHP function, for example, something I could run during a plugin's activation hook?

Thanks!!

Comment: You might also find this useful:

http://aaron.jorb.in/blog/2010/03/wordpress-external-cron-plugin/

Comment: Thanks for the link, and please correct me if I'm misunderstanding. I would write my plugin using WP-Cron and during setup, I would send the user's website to my central server. My central server would add the user's website to a list. The Aaron Jorbin plugin would then ping this list every 10 minutes, causing the WP-Cron job to fire.

Answer (score 1):

I think it´s impossible using only php (php couldn´t be started forewer it´s script). 
Maybe if you will be loading some page via ajax in cycle (problem - your device will need to stay online) or use some programming language no script. But cron is better solution ;)